# How to create global dataTable in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I need to use a global dataTable in my .net project. However, i cannot handle it between two methods..

In my example, dt1 is a global dataTable and dt2 is local, which dt2 is direct using to call another method.

result:
dt1: i don't know how to describe it, it likes the whole html page in excel.

dt2: very well!

Can you tell me why the dt1 is a wrong ? It should be perfect.. 
my code:

```
    private DataTable dt1;// same result as public DataTable dt1{ get; private set; }""
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (!Page.IsPostBack)
      {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("ShortURL", typeof(int)),
                            new DataColumn("LongURL", typeof(string)),
                            new DataColumn("CreatingDate",typeof(string)) });
                dt.Rows.Add(1, "John Hammond", "United States");
                dt.Rows.Add(2, "Mudassar Khan", "India");
                dt.Rows.Add(3, "Suzanne Mathews", "France");
                dt.Rows.Add(4, "Robert Schidner", "Russia");
           dt1 = dt;
      }
    }


    protected void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            dt2.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("ShortURL", typeof(int)),
                            new DataColumn("LongURL", typeof(string)),
                            new DataColumn("CreatingDate",typeof(string)) });
            dt2.Rows.Add(1, "John Hammond", "United States");
            dt2.Rows.Add(2, "Mudassar Khan", "India");
            dt2.Rows.Add(3, "Suzanne Mathews", "France");
            dt2.Rows.Add(4, "Robert Schidner", "Russia");

       exportToExcel(dt1);// fail :(
       exportToExcel(dt2);// success!

     }
```

Comment: Have you checked whether dt1 contains data or not?

Comment: I think so you need to set dt1 = new DataTable(); then dt1=dt; Try this.

Comment: @sowjanyaattaluri  i don't know how to describe it.. It contains some data, but not the data that i give it..

Comment: Copy content of dt to dt1 like dt1=dt.copy();

Comment: @sowjanyaattaluri i have already tried dt1 = new DataTable(); ...fail

Answer (score 1):

That's cause of the condition `if (!Page.IsPostBack)` and because of which in button click event when postback is happening you are not re-loading or populating the `dt1` and since it's a new page request with a new page instance the `dt1` is not present any more. Remove that condition altogether and test

```
private DataTable dt1;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("ShortURL", typeof(int)),
                        new DataColumn("LongURL", typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("CreatingDate",typeof(string)) });
            dt.Rows.Add(1, "John Hammond", "United States");
            dt.Rows.Add(2, "Mudassar Khan", "India");
            dt.Rows.Add(3, "Suzanne Mathews", "France");
            dt.Rows.Add(4, "Robert Schidner", "Russia");
}
```

(OR) store your datatable to a `session` and re-use it like

```
session["dt"] = dt1;

if(session["dt"] != null)
       exportToExcel((DataTable)session["dt"]);
```

Comment: i tried it already, however, my click function is going to change the value of it..Therefore, i put it into a if (!Page.IsPostBack) block..

Comment: Not sure what you are saying? Moreover if both datatable contains exact same data then you have two copies of it?

Comment: The data of my dataTable is coming from dataBase..Therefore, there may have an error if i try to asking dataBase double times..

Comment: You can use `Session` to store the datatable for later use. See answer for an example.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your definition of global is (the page containing the example or the entire project you speak of) so I used 3 different ways to retain the content in this example.
Your export fails because the contents of dt1 is lost on PostBack.

```
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("ShortURL", typeof(int)),
                        new DataColumn("LongURL", typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("CreatingDate",typeof(string)) });
            dt.Rows.Add(1, "John Hammond", "United States");
            dt.Rows.Add(2, "Mudassar Khan", "India");
            dt.Rows.Add(3, "Suzanne Mathews", "France");
            dt.Rows.Add(4, "Robert Schidner", "Russia");

            ViewState["yourTable"] = dt;
            // or
            Session["yourTable"] = dt;
            // or
            Application["yourTable"] = dt;
        }


    protected void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
        dt2.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("ShortURL", typeof(int)),
                        new DataColumn("LongURL", typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn("CreatingDate",typeof(string)) });
        dt2.Rows.Add(1, "John Hammond", "United States");
        dt2.Rows.Add(2, "Mudassar Khan", "India");
        dt2.Rows.Add(3, "Suzanne Mathews", "France");
        dt2.Rows.Add(4, "Robert Schidner", "Russia");

        if (ViewState["yourTable"] != null)
        {
            exportToExcel(ViewState["yourTable"] as DataTable);
        }
        // or
        if (Session["yourTable"] != null)
        {
            exportToExcel(Session["yourTable"] as DataTable);
        }
        // or
        if (Application["yourTable"] != null)
        {
            exportToExcel(Application["yourTable"] as DataTable);
        }

        exportToExcel(dt2);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple

First declare public(global) data table in form1.

eg: 
      public static DataTable dt;

Next assign your data to dt

in form2 declare 
        DataTable dt2 = from1.dt;

that's all.